# Commuting two pullbacks

Tags: category-theory

I have stumbled upon some interesting exercise whilst reading the "[Category Theory for Scientists](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/teaching/sp13/)" book.

[image]

Below is the **universal property of fiber products**:

[image]

By using the universal property, I can try placing some set *A*, connect it to the *X*, *X'*, *Y*, *Y'* through some functions and thus have two unique arrows spawning from it to the *W* and *W'*. However, nothing that could be used to create a direct connection between the *W* and *W'* comes out from that.

Any suggestions how this could be solved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the morphisms $W \to Y \to Y'$ and $W \to X \to X'$. Evidently they induce the same morphism $W \to Z'$. Hence, the universal property of $W'$ tells us that that they induce a morphism $W \to W'$ such that everything commutes (we don't need even need that $W$ is a pullback).

Comment: So basically the "W" pullback in the exercise can be looked at as the "A" set in the universal property definition, and the W -> Y -> Y' and W -> X -> X' morphisms as the "f" and "g" functions? :)

Comment: Yes. Remember that names of variables can be freely interchanged.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since the square on the face behind is a pullback, look for a pair of maps $W\to Y',\ W\to X'$ to form a commuting square with $Y'\to Z'$ and $X'\to Z'$.